# wordpress internationalization solution

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I have a request from a client to enable multiple language selection on his wordpress site. I have tried the http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/ and it is good but the problem is that the theme strings are not translated. And this plugin does not have an option for translating theme. 
So what are my options for having something like www.mydomain.com/en www.mydomain.com/de www.mydomain.com/fr...? 
Do I need to install multiple instances of wordpress to have that? 
Or there is a plugin that can translate the theme strings in the same way as qtranslate does for text entries?
What are the best practices please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not want to have multiple instances of WordPress to handle that. Check [WPML](http://wpml.org/) and [CMSwithTMS](http://www.cmswithtms.net). Former is the most advanced and commonly used multilingual publishing plugin for WordPress while latter is more suitable if your client is looking for a more complete workflow solution which uses a professional translation management system.

Comment: Thank you eakkas. I think we will go with WPML. The prices for a full version is not high and I think it's worth it. Didn't know about it's theme translation capabilities. If anything goes wrong I will update this thread. :)

Comment: @elector, note that it can only support theme translation if your theme is properly internationalized, not all themes are. Check that first as it may take some time to get it done if it is not.

Comment: the WPML plugin is not in the search results in the WP add new plugin page. I guess it needs to be paid and downloaded from their site? This is what I have suggested to my client. And if we can't use it there is money back guarantee. I hope :)